# How to set "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)" in cmake to vs2010?

Tags: compilation, cmake, compiler-warnings

I want add this in my CMake, but i not know how to do this. How to set "No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)" in cmake?

```
No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4khtbfyf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), `/INCREMENTAL` is a linker flag, so just add it to the appropriate variable. For example, this will set the flag for linking executable files:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} /INCREMENTAL:NO")
```

Or, if you just want it for one target, set it to the target's property:

```
set_property(TARGET YourTargetName APPEND_STRING PROPERTY LINK_FLAGS " /INCREMENTAL:NO")
```

There are per-configuration variants for both of these, as well as variants for other target types than executables. Just browse through [CMake docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/).